# Flutter video_player sound sometimes not in sync with video

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am having an issue with Flutter video_player where sometimes the video hangs and the sound is not in sync with the video. There is a delay of ~1 second between the video and sound. This only happens when playing certain videos, most videos are fine. I've checked that one of the affected videos is in the same format (mp4) as other videos and also have downloaded that video from my S3 bucket and have confirmed that it plays correctly in that case, so I believe it must be an issue with the video_player plugin. Here is my code to load the video controller. Is there any reason that videos would behave differently with this plugin where the audio and video are not in sync?

```
  void loadVideo() async {
    videoController =
        VideoPlayerController.network(videoLink);

    videoController.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        // displays an error message if the video controller doesn't load
        videoError = true;
        setState(() {});
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });

    videoController.addListener(_listenForError);
  }

  void playVideo() async {
    videoController.play();
  }

   Widget cameraWidget = Transform.scale(
      scale: videoController.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: videoController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: VideoPlayer(videoController),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Did you guys find a solution?

We are having the problem when we send the app to background and we return, it happens sometimes in iOS and old devices. Any ideas?

Comment: same issue, any updates?